# Is it somehow dangerous to spray compressed air into a CRT TV?

Tags: safety, consumer-electronics, engineering-history

I am planning to unscrew the plastic chassis of my big old CRT TV, after having it unplugged for 24 hours, and then spray compressed air all over the internals to remove all the heavy layers of dust inside.

I mean compressed air inside a can -- not some industrial-sized compressor thing. (I can't afford those in terms of money or physical size.)

I've been scared of this for a long time, asking many related questions and trying to learn everything about safety before I do something stupid.

Even if I never touch anything inside with my fingers (I will keep one hand in the pocket just in case), could leftover electricity somehow travel through the air backwards from the components into the can as I'm spraying it, electrocuting me this way? I won't be wearing any gloves or anything. Probably will tape the can to my hand just so I don't drop it too.

And if there is dust on the actual "tube"/screen part, is that more dangerous than spraying the component boards?

I'm taking a firm "better safe than sorry" stance on this project, even though I suspect that I won't be having any issues whatsoever besides the heavy lifting to bring it to the balcony and back.

Comment: @SolarMike It does not. It's why I asked this one to be specific.

Comment: Or this: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/51271/10902

Comment: @SolarMike I asked a specific question for a reason, and that reason is not to be redirected to irrelevant ones.

Comment: This question seems **so** similar to the others for some reason. However, I only get one vote, we will see what happens.

Comment: Under the "is it dangerous banner", I'd believe if it was the other questions would of referenced if electricity could travel up the compressed air stream.  It can't.  Just because you believe it is irrelevant is immaterial.  We don't and this is essentially a duplicate question.

Comment: I fail to see how the linked answers don't answer your question. Your question is almost an exact duplicate of the first link.

Comment: why are you using more than one user account?